# Use cases for List.compare in OCaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, compare, ocaml

I don't fully understand the type interface of `List.compare`which is:

`('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a list -> int`

Are there any other use cases beside those examples:

```
List.compare (+) [1;3] [2;2];;
- : int = 3

List.compare (-) [1;3] [2;2];;
- : int = -1

List.compare (/) [1;3] [2;2];;
- : int = 1

List.compare ( * ) [1;3] [2;2];;
- : int = 2
```

This is quite a trivial question but the documentation is very minimalistic.

Comment: [The documentation](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALcompare) explains it quite clearly I think. It refers specifically to [`Stdlib.compare`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#VALcompare) for the comparison function which further explains the expected interface, which only `-` conforms to in your examples. For `int`s you should be using `Int.compare` instead, for `string`s you could use `String.compare` etc.

Comment: Three way comparison is very useful for ordered data structures like trees, or sorting.

Comment: Instead of calling `List.compare Int.compare` (or something similar) directly, using [`ppx_compare`](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_compare#comparison-without-a-type-definition) by calling `[%compare: int list] [1; 3] [2; 2]` can be a bit more legible.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that you can lift a comparison function that works on some type into a comparison function that works on lists of the type. There are many ways to do this, but the obvious one is to use lexicographic order.

As @glennsl points out, only one of your examples makes any sense. You need to supply a comparison function for `List.compare` to lift. You can't supply an arbitrary function (if you want to get meanginful results).